# Prettier keep space in empty curly brace { }

Tags: javascript, prettier

I want to keep a single space between curly braces, like here

```
class Entity {
    constructor(
        readonly id: string
    ) { } // <-- single space
}
```

However when I save, `prettier` removes it, resulting in

```
class Entity {
    constructor(
        readonly id: string
    ) {}
}
```

I have `bracketSpacing: true` in my `prettierrc.json`, is that not the correct rule for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

and for more details you can check this documentation https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html

```
{
"arrowParen":"singleline",
"bracketSpacing":true,
}

,,,
```